# "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)" when attempting to SSH from server 1 to server 2

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sshd

I'm trying to ssh from my backup server (CentOS 7) to my production server (CentOS 8), to pull a database backup.

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm using root on both servers.  I've taken the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on BACKUP and put it in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (owner: `root`, perms: `644`) of PROD.

When I issue this command...

```
rsync -av -e 'ssh -p 222' root@PROD_IP:/var/www/sites/DB_backup_* /home/DB/
```

...I get this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

sshd_config on PROD:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
AllowUsers mynamehere
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
ClientAliveCountMax 5
ClientAliveInterval 60
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin without-password
Port 222
PrintMotd no
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
UseDNS no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
```

(excuse the unusual order - used a quick `:sort` in vim to get rid of all the comments for the purpose of this post)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see you passing in the private key to `rsync`/`ssh`

Comment: This still gives me the same error:

`rsync -av -e 'ssh -p 222 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa' root@PROD_IP:/var/www/sites/DB_backup_* /home/DB/`

Comment: You're right, I wasn't.  I wasn't aware I needed to, but adding it doesn't seem to have helped.  Any ideas, @Panki ?

Comment: AllowUsers was the problem.  I didn't realise that root needed to be listed in there when the PermitRootLogin declaration strongly implies that root is allowed already!

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`AllowUsers` not including `root`. was the problem.

Changing

```
AllowUsers myname
```

to

```
AllowUsers myname root
```

fixed it.

I didn't realise that `root` needed to be listed in there when the `PermitRootLogin` declaration strongly implies that `root` is already allowed!

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions:

```
-rw------- 1 user user  822 feb 28  2019 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 user user   81 dic 14  2018 config
-rw------- 1 user user 1675 dic 14  2018 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  406 dic 14  2018 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  222 apr 24  2019 known_hosts
```

they must be like that

Comment: They were - I solved it if you look at the comments on the question.